# UIModalPresentationFormSheet Resizing and Human Interface Guidelines

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, human-interface

I was just wondering if it was alright to resize (or move) a presented view controller, like one with UIModalPresentationFormSheet style or if this is against Apple Human Interface Guidelines.

As stated in the HIG document, "Form sheet. Has fixed dimensions of 540 x 620 points and is centered in the screen", "When the keyboard is visible in landscape, a form sheet view moves up to just below the status bar" and "This style is good for gathering structured information from the user".

So, would it be a violation of the HIG if I use another dimension, I choose another behavior for when the keyboard shows or if I use an all different paradigm to gather structured information? (Like, for example, not even using two different view controllers to gather and display information)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer no, you are not violating hig in this case. you can change that behavior and you should be fine with apple guidelines as well.